# bash: use a pattern to get all files at once

Tags: bash, pattern-matching

I have a script that takes as an argument a list of files to analyze. It can be any number of files.

```
$ ./myScript file1 file2 ... fileN
```

Now, I have to run it on a large number files (~30) whose paths can be  easily exploited with a pattern. With `find` I can find them one by one and apply the script on each of them, but what I want is to take them all and **run** the script **on all of them** at once.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find ... -exec ./myScript {} +
```

This *might* result in more than one call to `myScript` if there are too many matches (i.e. the command line gets too long), but there is little you could do to avoid multiple calls in that case anyway (short of passing the pattern itself as parameter to `myScript` and do the pattern-matching internally).

Comment: Thanks. So is it the `+` instead of the usual backslash to make the difference here?

Comment: @RickyRobinson: Correct. `{} \;` is one call per match, `{} +` is multiple matches per call. Check `man find`; that tool has a **lot** to offer beyond simple find-by-pattern-and-print. It is very worthwhile to learn what it can do.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the $() to make the list of found arguments into an array?

I used to use `javac -d . $(find . -name '*.java' -a ! -name '.*')` to compile all java files in a directory.

Comment: Note that this fails if you have spaces in your filenames. (You shouldn't, but it happens.)

Comment: Err... sorry? What does require multiple executions? (I did not get your meaning there.)

Comment: Oh, the form of putting the find results into an array and then calling a function on it. Does this require multiple calls to the function? (the function is javac in my example)

Comment: No, it doesn't. The content of `$(...)` is executed, the `$()` itself replaced with the output of the execution (the list of files, in this example), and the resulting line (`javac -d . <list_of_files>`) executed again. This works just fine most of the time, *unless* there are files with spaces in their names, because the knowledge that e.g. `"./foo bar.java"` is a single file is lost in the substitution - you'd end up with the line `javac -d . ./foo bar.java` and a compiler error (since neither "./foo" nor "bar.java" exist). `find ... -exec ... {} +` avoids that issue.

Comment: Ah substitution. Thanks for that insight mate. Also, people using bash shouldn't have spaces in file names ;)   Just messin, it happens.

Comment: No-one should have spaces in file names; sooner or later, someone *will* want to access the data with a script of some kind (as Bash, Perl etc. exist on Windows as well), and you get bitten. Glad I could be of help.